# reactjs: Unexpected token Tabs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use react-tabs here https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs to create tabs on my UI. This is my code so far:

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TabsApp from './TabsApp.jsx';

main();

function main() {
    render(<TabsApp/>, document.getElementById('container'));
}
```

And this is my TabsApp.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';

class TabsApp extends Component {
  handleSelect(index, last) {
    console.log('Selected tab: ' + index + ', Last tab: ' + last);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {}

      <Tabs
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        selectedIndex={2}
      >

        {}

        <TabList>

          {}

          <Tab>Foo</Tab>
          <Tab>Bar</Tab>
          <Tab>Baz</Tab>
        </TabList>

        {}

        <TabPanel>
          <h2>Hello from Foo</h2>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <h2>Hello from Bar</h2>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <h2>Hello from Baz</h2>
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

But this is the error I'm getting:

> ```
> ERROR in ./TabsApp.jsx
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/x/TabsApp.jsx: Unexpected token (14:8)
>
>       <Tabs
>         onSelect={this.handleSelect}
>         selectedIndex={2}
>       >
> ```

Can anyone please help me?

I'm using webpack dev server. And 0.14.7 react

Comment: Which is the unxpected token? Seems to me that webpack isn't set up to handle the jsx in your file...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue is in index.jsx. You are not using react to render the component. Your index.jsx should look like :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TabsApp from './TabsApp.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <TabsApp />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got

```
  render() {
    return (
      {}

      <Tabs
```

Get rid of that random `{}` there. You can't return an empty object AND a `<Tabs>` component.

[erichardson30](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667645/65387) is also correct... that's another problem.